# Separate Window Thread Closure

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a WPF app that when a button is clicked, a new Window (`BrowserWindow`) is instantiated that loads a full screen `WebBrowser` control. The Window is kicked off on a second thread like this.

```
private void BrowserThreadStart(BrowserWindow browser, String address)
{
    browser = new BrowserWindow();
    browser.LoadPage(address);
    browser.Show();
    System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
}

private void Press(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Thread mainBrowserThread = new Thread(() => BrowserThreadStart(myBrowser, "http://www.google.com"));
    mainBrowserThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    mainBrowserThread.IsBackground = true;
    mainBrowserThread.Start();
}
```

That much works great.

Based on this, what is the proper way for my `MainWindow` to programatically Hide or Close the `BrowserWindow` instance running on  the separate thread?

I noticed on my main thread (in MainWindow), the `BrowserWindow myBrowser` is null (even though I can see it up and running on the second thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are "passing by value" which means BrowserThreadStart is modify a copy of the reference not the reference.  You need to add [ref or out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) to browser in your BrowserThreadStart method declaration and method call.  Here is an example you can substitute ref for out, depending on need and preference.

Try changing:

```
private void BrowserThreadStart(BrowserWindow browser, String address)
```

to

```
private void BrowserThreadStart(out BrowserWindow browser, String address)
```

and

```
Thread mainBrowserThread = new Thread(() => BrowserThreadStart(myBrowser, "http://www.google.com"));
```

to

```
Thread mainBrowserThread = new Thread(() => BrowserThreadStart(out myBrowser, "http://www.google.com"));
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll give this a try. Somewhat off topic question but is there a term for the "() =>" syntax. Never seen anything like that before and am trying to decipher what operators/operations are happening in what order.

Comment: @Ternary, It's called a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).